# Remove specific lines

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I'd like to remove a few lines from a csv file.

The rules are simple enough (Keep line if):

- It's the first line in the file.
- The first value is different from the first value of the previous row.
- The second value has increased by at least 10 from the previous kept line.

Source

```
Test1,  0.0, 1
Test1,  0.2, 1
Test1, 10.0, 3
Test2,  0.1, 1
Test2,  0.3, 3
Test2,  1.0, 5
Test2, 11.0, 7
```

Result

```
Test1,  0.0, 1
Test1, 10.0, 3
Test2,  0.1, 1
Test2, 11.0, 7
```

I was thinking of doing this with awk and a few if statements, but I'm not certain if I can make a variable that is transferred between record processing.

---

EDIT: this was hidden in the comments section (from me):

I just found out that the variables are usable between records. Something that doesn't work quite like C. I'll remove this question unless someone gives an answer that I deem usable for others or someone asks me to provide the answer.

Comment: I guess the input is formatted that way for fanciness, correct? I.e. the output shall contain just the comma-separated values with no whitespace, correct?

Comment: This is correct. Just to make it easier to read.

Comment: Ok, however apparently the last value in the output doesn't meet the third condition: the value of the second field increased by `10.9`, not by `10`.

Comment: Yeah, the rule is wrong, fixed.

Comment: I just found out that the variables are usable between records. Something that doesn't work quite like C++. I'll remove this question unless someone gives an answer that I deem usable for others or someone asks me to provide the answer.

Comment: If you want I almost have a Perl solution. I'm just having troubles associating terms in the expression for the last condition, not sure why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32045/discussion-between-0xbaadf00d-and-kos).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it's tagged with awk

```
awk -F", *" 'x!=$1||$2>=y+10{y=$2;print}{x=$1}' file


Test1,  0.0, 1
Test1, 10.0, 3
Test2,  0.1, 1
Test2, 11.0, 7
```

Comment: I commented on the question, that I found out that the variables actually work between records. I though they wouldn't, because i thought the program was executed for each line, like a C function. I'll move it to the question itself.

Comment: @0xbaadf00d Sorry, I don't understand what you mean, what variables ? And what do you mean by "work" ?

Comment: In your case x and y. For whatever silly reason, I thought that they wouldn't be shared between records(lines). But nevermind, it works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl:

```
perl -lane 'if($.==1||"$F[0]"ne"$F0"||$F[1]>=$F1+10){print;$F1=@F[1]}$F0=@F[0]' file
```

Expanded:

```perl
if($. == 1 || "$F[0]" ne "$F0" || $F[1] >= $F1 + 10){
    print;
    $F1 = @F[1]
}
$F0 = @F[0]
```

- `if($.==1||"$F[0]"ne"$F0"||$F[1]>=$F1+10){print;$F1=@F[1]}`: if the current line's number is `1`, the current line's first field is equal to the previous line's first field or the current line's second field is greater or equal to the previous line's second field, prints the current line and assigns the value of the current line's second field to `F1`;
- `$F0=@F[0]`: assigns the value of the current line's first field to `F0`;

```
% cat file
Test1,  0.0, 1
Test1,  0.2, 1
Test1, 10.0, 3
Test2,  0.1, 1
Test2,  0.3, 3
Test2,  1.0, 5
Test2, 11.0, 7
% perl -lane 'if($.==1||"$F[0]"ne"$F0"||$F[1]>=$F1+10){print;$F1=@F[1]}$F0=@F[0]' file
Test1,  0.0, 1
Test1, 10.0, 3
Test2,  0.1, 1
Test2, 11.0, 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a Python script:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import sys
with open (sys.argv[1]) as f:
  rows=[list(map(str.strip, line.split(','))) for line in f.readlines()]
  result=rows[0:1]
  for r in rows:
    if r[0] != result[-1][0] or float(r[1]) >= float(result[-1][1])+10:
      result.append(r)
  print("\n".join([",".join(res) for res in result]))
```

Copy the script above and paste it into a file called `csvfilter.py` for example.
Make it executable using `chmod +x csvfilter.py`.

Then you can run it from the command-line with the csv file to process (I saved your example from the question as `source.csv`) as argument:

```
$ ./csvfilter.py source.csv 
Test1,0.0,1
Test1,10.0,3
Test2,0.1,1
Test2,11.0,7
```

The script will not modify the original file, but just print the new version to the standard output. Also, any previous formatting using spaces will be discarded.

To replace the original file with the modified version, redirect the output back to the original file:

```
$ ./csvfilter.py source.csv > source.csv
```

You can also save the modified version as a file:

```
$ ./csvfilter.py source.csv > modified.csv
```

Comment: Is this ok or do you prefer the original whitespace formatting to be preserved or the source file to get directly modified?

Comment: OP said it's fine: http://askubuntu.com/questions/701948/remove-specific-lines#comment1029766_701948

Comment: This is ok, whitespace was just to make it easier to read. I will plot graphs out of the data, so the numbers will not be read directly.